# Can't figure out how to get BS4 to retrieve youtube view count on /videos page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am trying to navigate to a page using BS4, lets use /history for an example. I want to gather the viewcount for all the videos that are currently on the /history channel. To obtain a list view of all videos I go to https://www.youtube.com/history/videos

I then use inspect element in chrome to find the tags. Which gives me the conclusion that I should try a "span" with the class="style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer"

This doesn't work for some reason and I can't for the life of me understand this.

```
import re
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time


theurl = "https://www.youtube.com/history/videos"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
Views = soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class':'class="style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer"'})
print(Views)
```

I would like it to print out the following output

3.5k
1.2k
2.2k
5.5k

I can then learn on my own that for every instance of K, I multiply by 100, etc M and B.

However getting to the step where it prints out the views is my current roadblock.

Comment: Are you interested in the number of views of videos in the top of the page your url refers to or the views of ALL the videos in the channel - that can be obtained by continuously scrolling down the page; there are probably hundreds or maybe thousands (didn't scroll all the way to the last video...).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the tag you found is there so that javascript can output the views of the video. Urllib don't get javascript outputs. Try using Selenium.